# Использование условных операторов в C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace MyFirstProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int myNum = 5;
            if (myNum = 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("5 = 5");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Что здесь не правильно? Подчеркивает красным `myNum = 5` после ключевого слова `if`.

Comment: Одно `=` это присваивание. Если вы сравниваете что-то, то используйте сравнение `==`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вместо присвоения

```
if (myNum = 5)
         ^^^
```

здесь должно быть сравнение

```
if (myNum == 5)
         ^^^^
```

Также вы могли бы вывод на консоль сделать более содержательным. Например

```
Console.WriteLine("myNum == 5 is {0}", myNum == 5);
```

Answer (score 4):

Небольшая заметка о различиях между языками:

`(myNum = 5)` — это выражение присваивания. Оно возвращает присвоенное значение `5` типа `int`. Однако это значение не приводится автоматически к типу `bool`.  Это сделано специально, чтобы предотвратить такие опечатки, как ваша.

Однако, в других языках, например C++, возвращаемый результат автоматически приводится к типу `bool`, и поэтому может использоваться в различных необычных конструкциях:

```
if (a = 5) //true
{
    ...
}

if (b = 0) //false
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Хм, не совсем так. В C# `myNum = 5` является-таки выражением со значением 5. Вы можете это легко проверить: `int x; int y = x = 5;`. Разница в том, что в C# `int` не приводится автоматически к типу `bool`, в отличие от C++. А в `if` нужно именно выражение типа `bool`.

Comment: В C++ в `if` нужен `bool`, но `int` приводится к нему. А в C в `if` нужен и вовсе `int`.

Comment: Поэтому в C# не скомпилируется `if (5)`. Зато скомпилируется `bool b; if (b = true)`.

Comment: Ну, все тонкости на этом закончились :) На самом деле, по уму надо бы, чтобы `a = b` не было выражением, ясно же. Но C# хотел сохранить совместимость с Java, которая хотела сохранить совместимость с C++, который хотел сохранить совместимость с C, который вообще обожает конструкции типа `if ((f = fopen()) && (n = fread(f, buf)))` [в доме, который построил Джек].